# Unable to PUT object on digital ocean spaces when body of fetch is Buffer

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fetch, digital-ocean, cloudflare-workers

I am learning cloudflare workers and I need to store objects on spaces by digital ocean.

If you are not aware, cloudflare workers can't use the regular `aws-sdk` js library since it uses `XMLHttpRequest` which is unavailable on the worker's isolates.

I'm working on manual PUT using the spaces API and I'm able to upload plain text objects to the bucket without any issue.

The problem starts when I attempt to PUT an image using the constructor `new Buffer.from(...some image content as base64...,'base64')`, the error I'm getting from spaces API is `XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch` and I think the issue is when I hash the body to `sha256` using the `crypto-js` library, but I can't figure out why.

```js
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256'
import hmacSha256 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256'

export default class SpacesClient {
    constructor( config ){
        this.accessKey = config.accessKey;
        this.secretKey = config.secretKey;
        this.region = config.region;
        this.domain = config.domain || 'digitaloceanspaces.com';
    }

    getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
        let keyDate = hmacSha256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
        let keyRegion = hmacSha256(regionName, keyDate);
        let keyService = hmacSha256(serviceName, keyRegion);
        return hmacSha256("aws4_request", keyService);
    }


    //TODO: everything works great if body is text, the next step is to check why it doesn't work when it is Buffer
    signAndSendRequest( { method , bucket , path , body , acl , contentType } ){
        const amzdate = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:-]|\.\d{3}/g, '');
        const datestamp = amzdate.slice(0, 8)

        const service = 's3';
        const host = (this.domain !== 'digitaloceanspaces.com')
            ? `${bucket}.${service}.${this.region}.${this.domain}`
            : `${bucket}.${this.region}.${this.domain}`

        const endpoint = `https://${host}${path}`;
        acl = acl === 'public-read' ? 'public-read' : 'private';

        const canonicalUri = path;
        const canonicalQuerystring = '';
        const payloadHash = sha256(body).toString();
        const canonicalHeaders = `content-type:${contentType}\nhost:${host}\nx-amz-acl:${acl}\nx-amz-content-sha256:${payloadHash}\nx-amz-date:${amzdate}\n`;
        const signedHeaders = 'content-type;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date';
        const algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';

        const canonicalRequest = `${method}\n${canonicalUri}\n${canonicalQuerystring}\n${canonicalHeaders}\n${signedHeaders}\n${payloadHash}`;

        const credentialScope = `${datestamp}/${this.region}/${service}/aws4_request`;
        const stringToSign = `${algorithm}\n${amzdate}\n${credentialScope}\n${sha256(canonicalRequest)}`;

        const signingKey = this.getSignatureKey(this.secretKey, datestamp, this.region, service);
        const signature = hmacSha256(stringToSign, signingKey);

        const authorizationHeader = `${algorithm} Credential=${this.accessKey}/${credentialScope},SignedHeaders=${signedHeaders},Signature=${signature}`;

        const params = {
            method: method,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
                'content-type': contentType,
                'x-amz-acl': acl,
                'x-amz-content-sha256': payloadHash,
                'x-amz-date': amzdate,
            },
        };

        if ( body ) params.body = body;

        return fetch( endpoint, params );
    }

    getObject( params ) {
        return this.signAndSendRequest( { method: 'GET' , ...params } );
    }

    putObject(params) {
        return this.signAndSendRequest( { method: 'PUT' , ...params } );
    }

    deleteObject(params) {
        return this.signAndSendRequest( { method: 'DELETE' , ...params } );
    }
}
```

It works great when the body variable is a string and the contentType is `text/plain`,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question, but I recommend this library for talking to AWS from Cloudflare Workers: https://github.com/mhart/aws4fetch (Aside: Note that `crypto-js` is very slow since it implements crypto in pure JS. Workers supports the `WebCrypto` API, which is much faster, and aws4fetch uses it.)

Comment: I found aws4fetch at the begining but I don't remember why I didn't use it, the point is, I used the worker's `WebCrypto` API and it works now ( I don't know why honestly ), and my js bundle went from 826kb to 52kb, great catch @KentonVarda